# Egress window, drop it or change design

Tags: basement-refinishing, design, egress

Purchased a house with unfinshed basement. The layout is dodgy so I am trying to keep the bedroom in the left corner to have a larger living space. I know I need an egress window and there is a small one. Do I make the bedroom larger to have both windows or what would the cost/work or steps be to move the small window down?

Comment: What is the wall made of?  Most basements have concrete or cement block walls.

Comment: Pictures and diagrams/drawings would help. It's generally possible but can be prohibitively expensive to change or add window and door (recall that a door directly to outside also works for an egress) openings in concrete basement walls.

Comment: This is far too vague. A ceiling height below 7 ft, for instance, is a deal killer. You really need to include images. At that point, the comments may be far more interesting than the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Technically the door to upstairs is the egress and a window is an "emergency escape and rescue opening." The modern spec for such a window is at [IRC R310](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-3-building-planning#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch03_SecR310). If a basement has bedrooms, then the whole basement's emergency escape can be the emergency window in each bedroom. If you're creating a bedroom or modifying one under a building permit, then be prepared to bring a window into compliance with the area, height, width, and distance above finished floor requirements from R310.

You'll have to be much more specific if you want a specific description of the scope of work. Pricing is out of bounds for this forum, but with a proper scope of work, you can at least solicit more than one bid for the exact same scope of work. Otherwise it's difficult to compare contractors (under a vague "finish my basement" scope).